# How to get the file extension in JfileChooser if the user input the filename without extension

Tags: java

I used the JFileChooser in my app.  My question is if the user typing file name without the file extension on the dialog box; the app will allow more another file extension.  How can I get the file extension on the file as type drop down box. I used fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName() or fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() didn't get the extension. Would someone help me how to do it.

[image]

There is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    private String getSavedFileName()
    {
        String rtnValue="";  
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();  
        String PDFEXTENSION= "pdf";
        FileNameExtensionFilter  pdfType=new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF File (."+ PDFEXTENSION + ")", PDFEXTENSION);
        fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pdfType);
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(pdfType);
        //clear "All files" from dropdown filter box
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this.splitRightPane);
        if (returnVal ==  fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

              File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
             // String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1, file.getName().length());   
              String fileAbsolutePath=file.getName();
              file.getAbsolutePath()
              String extension =fileAbsolutePath.substring(fileAbsolutePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileAbsolutePath.length() );

              if ( PDFEXTENSION.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)){
                    rtnValue=fileAbsolutePath;

                  } else{
                     Utility.DisplayWarningMsg("Only PDF File");
                  }

          } else if (returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION ) {
          // Do something else

          } 
        return rtnValue;
    }
```